# Injecting Spring Data Repositories in Junit 5 Tests

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I am trying to inject a spring data repository in a Junit 5 test but I am getting

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.xxx.core.security.datastore.AccountsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate
```

here is the test

```
package com.xxx.core.security.datastore;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

@SpringJUnitConfig
class AccountsRepositoryTest {


    @Autowired
    AccountsRepository accountsRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Assumptions.assumeTrue(true); // how to get spring profile ! 
    }

    @Test
    public void name() {

    }
}
```

And here is my repo

```
package com.xxx.core.security.datastore;

import com.checkit.core.security.datastore.model.Account;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface AccountsRepository extends CrudRepository<Account,Long> {
    Account findByName(String name);
}
```

When I run the application spring seems to wire everything

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by including a config class to the annotation and a test property source, in Junit as far as I remember this was not needed as the test configs were by default.

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(CoreApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource("/application.properties")
class AccountsRepositoryTest {


    @Autowired
    AccountsRepository accountsRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Assumptions.assumeTrue(true); // how to get spring profile ! 
    }

    @Test
    public void name() {
    }
}
```